# Asynchronous access to window.external (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm assisting to develop a JavaScript web application that's embedded into an external vendors software product.  Our web application is given standard access to the parent applications data via calling ***window.external***.

What we've found is that when operations run slow within the parent application (e.g. `window.external.getMyDate("big data")`) it locks our browser window. We have no control over the interface or parent application but are there any ways to run calls like this asynchronous within JavaScript (using a call back similar to how a AJAX call works)?

The goal is that our web application doesn't lock while we're accessing the parent data.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: web workers? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp